# Errores desconocidos en Bash/Shell

Tags: bash, shell

¡Hola a todos!
He tenido unos inconvenientes con mi código, y es que al ejecutarlo desde un tiempo empezó a mostrarme errores que simplemente no sé solucionar. ¿Una manita?

MI CÓDIGO:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Coded by Krypt0N

items=("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZton86SuOg" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3XcNskAxp0" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE84i9D9naA" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKylgPPzJHk" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iU7oF4OXZSE" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdlWG29Flow" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSkDfGa9Bnw" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F9N-6ITFnA" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCkJ5lGPqFs")

size=${#items[@]}
randomindex=$(($RANDOM % $size))

echo -e "\e[1;4;35mIf you want to stop playing press (CTRL + C)"

mpv ${items[$randomindex]}

CANCION=${items[$randomindex]}

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZton86SuOg" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Material Girl - Madonna" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6F9N-6ITFnA" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Da Ya Think I'm Sexy? - Rod Stewart" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCkJ5lGPqFs" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Out of Touch - D. Hall & J. Oates" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSkDfGa9Bnw" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Brother Louie - Modern Talking" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TdlWG29Flow" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Cheri Cheri Lady - Modern Talking" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iU7oF4OXZSE" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Lose Yourself to Dance - Daft Punk" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKylgPPzJHk" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Sugar - Maroon 5" | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE84i9D9naA" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Daddy Cool - Boney M." | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3XcNskAxp0" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Ma Baker - Boney M." | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi

if [ "$CANCION" == "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f3XcNskAxp0" ]
then
    echo 
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
        echo -e "\e[1mThis was: Ma Baker - Boney M." | lolcat
     echo -e "\e[91m------------------------------------------------------"
         echo
fi


echo -e "\e[93mDo you wanna listen another song?"
 select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) bash MRPop; exit;;

         No ) 
         echo -e "\e[94mDo you wanna listen another genre?"
                select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
                    case $yn in
                        Yes ) bash MUDATOR.sh; exit;;
                        No ) clear; echo "See you later!" | lolcat -a; exit;;
                        * ) echo "Please choice a valid option!";;
                            esac
                                            done;;   

    * ) echo "Please choice a valid option!";;
    esac
done
```

Los errores se encuentran en la siguiente imagen (en un repositorio de github):https://github.com/Krypt0N-Geek/errors_to_debug/blob/master/Captura%20de%20pantalla%20de%202019-10-01%2020-59-28.png

Cualquier duda, el repositorio completo se encuentra en mi perfil de git y se llama "MUDATOR_gnulinux". Como extra es un programa que reproduce canciones de youtube utilizando MPV... Gracias!!

Comment: Por las dudas prueba quitar saltos de línea DOS, mediante `dos2unix tu_script` y nos cuentas

Comment: @PatricioMoracho ¡Un genio, como siempre! ¡¡¡Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

En la imagen de los errores parace que el primer `(` esta incluido en el `string` asi `(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZton86SuOg`. Pero cuando copié tu código en mi terminal funcionó bien.

A lo mejor es un error con las configuraciones de gnu bash?

Comment: No estoy seguro, te comento que desde un tiempo hacia ahorita empezó a mostrar ese error. Lo raro es que no he movido nada de configuración, pues es un sistema virgen (sin nada instalado más que las utilidades integradas y las dependencias del programa)